# Unable to update Angular from 10 to 11 due to dependency errors

Tags: angular, npm-install, angular10, angular-upgrade, npm-update

I am following this [site](https://update.angular.io/?v=10.2-11.0) and trying to update my project to 11.0 through the following command.

```
npx @angular/cli@11 update @angular/core@11 @angular/cli@11
```

Every time I run it, it gives me the following error:

```
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: my-first-app@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.1002.4
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!   dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"~0.1102.17" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"~0.1102.17" from the root project
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/compiler-cli@11.2.14
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli
npm ERR!   peer @angular/compiler-cli@"^11.0.0 || ^11.2.0-next" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.1102.17
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!     dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"~0.1102.17" from the root project
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
```

On other similar questions, I have found this command being referred to a lot

```
npm install --legacy-peer-deps
```

I am not sure how the above command can help since I have already run **npm install** and just trying to upgrade now with `npx @angular/cli@11 update @angular/core@11 @angular/cli@11`

Environment details:

```
Global Angular CLI: 13.1.2
Local Angular CLI: 10.2.4
Angular version: 10.2.5
Node: 16.13.1
```

What different can I do to make it work?

Comment: Add `--force` after your update command?

Comment: @R.Richards --force didn't help.

Answer (score 11):

I could solve it this way:

After running the below upgrade command

> npx @angular/cli@11 update @angular/core@11 @angular/cli@11

It fails with same error but it changes `package.json` file for angular packages. So run below command without changing package.json:

> npm i --legacy-peer-deps

`--legacy-peer-deps` is important here. Then run the upgrade command again and it should work:

> npx @angular/cli@11 update @angular/core@11 @angular/cli@11

Comment: Worked for me but I had to add `--allow-dirty` to the second ng update

Comment: This doesn't work for me. The packages are all updated, but the actual angular updates that take place within the typescript file are not attempted as it detects the angular version of the installed packages is already at 11. So I get messages saying Package '@angular/core' is already up to date.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem so changed some dependency versions in `package.json`

```
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/animations": "^11.2.14",
  "@angular/cdk": "11.0.4",
  "@angular/common": "^11.2.14",
  "@angular/compiler": "^11.2.14",
  "@angular/core": "^11.2.14",
  "@angular/forms": "^11.2.14",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "^11.2.14",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^11.2.14",
  "@angular/router": "^11.2.14",
}

"devDependencies": {
  "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1102.6",
  "@angular/cli": "^11.2.17",
  "@angular/compiler-cli": "^11.2.14",
  "@angular/language-service": "11.2.14"
}
```

remove `node_modules` and run `npm i` again.

Answer (score -2):

1- go to [Nodejs](https://nodejs.org) website and update your version to the latest LTS version.

2- go to your OS command line and run `npm i -g npm` to update your npm to the latest version.

3- Update your global Angular Version to v11.0 by `npm uninstall` and `npm install` again,

4- if none of this works try to update on a different computer.